# Filtrando registros por fecha por medio de un date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

he estado intentando filtrar los registros por fecha utilizando un date_select, sin embargo no logro conseguirlo, para esto utilizo el siguiente formulario de busqueda:

```
<%= form_tag({ controller: :outputs, action: :index }, { method: :get } ) do %>        
    <div class="grid-x date">
     <%= date_select :date_of_issue, {} %>                         
     <%= submit_tag "Filtrar", date_of_issue: nil, class: "button" %>                             
    </div>          
<% end %>
```

Obteniendo la siguiente URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/outputs?utf8=✓&date_of_issue[{}(3i)]=&date_of_issue[{}(2i)]=&date_of_issue[{}(1i)]=&commit=Filtrar
```

Sin embargo no es una url limpia con una fecha parseada, por lo que he intentado opciones como esta en el controlador:

```
date_of_issue = params[:date_of_issue]
start_date = Date.new(date_of_issue["{}(3i)"].to_i, date_of_issue["{}(2i)"].to_i, date_of_issue["{}(1i)"].to_i)
```

Obteniendo como error: `invalid date`

¿De que forma podria setear la fecha para que se puedan filtrar los registros? Anexo mi codigo general:

```
  <%= form_tag({ controller: :outputs, action: :index }, { method: :get } ) do %>        
      <div class="grid-x date">
         <%= date_select :date_of_issue, {},{  :order => [:day, :month, :year], :start_year => 2016, :end_year => Time.current.year, :prompt => { :day => 'Dia', :month => 'Mes', :year => 'Año' }}, { class: "cell large-4 medium-4 small-4 border-right-none" } %>                         
        <%= submit_tag "Filtrar", date_of_issue: nil, class: "button" %>                             
      </div>          
  <% end %>          

  <div class="table-scroll">
    <table class="unstriped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8"><h6 class="margin-bottom-0">Reporte General de Ventas</h6></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="8%">Fecha</th>
          <th width="8%" class="text-right">N° Factura</th>
          <th width="18%" class="text-right">Tipo de factura</th>
          <th width="40%" class="text-right">Cliente</th>            
          <th width="8%" class="text-right">Efectivo</th>
          <th width="8%" class="text-right">Credito</th>
          <th width="1%" colspan="2" class="text-right">Opciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% if @outputs.any? %>
          <% @outputs.each do |output| %>
             <td width="10%"><%= output.date_of_issue.strftime("%d-%m-%y") %></td>
             <td class="text-right"><%= link_to output.invoice_number, output %></td>
          </tr>
       <% end %>
       <% else %>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="6">No se ha encontrado ningún registro</td>
       </tr>
     <% end %>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

**outputs_controller.rb**

```
 def index
      if params[:date_of_issue].present?  
        date_of_issue = params[:date_of_issue]
        date = Date.new(date_of_issue["{}(3i)"].to_i, date_of_issue["{}(2i)"].to_i, date_of_issue["{}(1i)"].to_i)

        @outputs = Output.where(date_of_issue: date)
      else
        @outputs = Output.where(date_of_issue: (Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month))
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo del todo a que te refieres con:

> una url limpia con una fecha parseada

El date select funciona de esa manera, genera 3 selects y envía los tres como parámetros distintos. Quizás no sea la opción más bonita, pero es como funciona y cumple su objetivo de enviar una fecha al backend. 
Tu problema de `invalid date` es porque estás pasando los parámetros al revés, [el orden correcto](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#class-Date-label-Date) es año, mes, día. Aplicado a tu código:

```
start_date = Date.new(date_of_issue["{}(1i)"].to_i, 
                      date_of_issue["{}(2i)"].to_i, 
                      date_of_issue["{}(3i)"].to_i)
```

Si lo que te molesta en la url es ese `{}`, según [la documentación de rails](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select), el primer parámetro a pasar es el `object_name` y el segundo es el `method`, así que como estás pasando un hash vacío como segundo parámetro, es la razón por la cual los parámetros aparecen como `date_of_issue[{}(3i)]`. Una solución es que pases `nil` como 2do parámetro, así te generaría un parámetro del tipo `date_of_issue[(3i)]`.

Por último, pero no menos importante ¿no has considerado usar alguna librería js para manejar las fechas en vez de los built-in de rails?. Insisto con que `date_select` cumple con su cometido, pero hay [bastante más librerías](https://github.com/sorrycc/awesome-javascript#calendar) allí afuera, para distintos frameworks que uses en el frontend, que lo hacen mucho mejor que rails, entre eso, mandar la fecha en un puro parámetro o elegir la fecha en un puro campo en vez de 3 selects.

Comment: He puesto el orden correcto Alter y he obtenido esto: `undefined method []' for nil:NilClass` en cuanto al segundo parametro, sobre nil, no logre entenderlo, viendo ejemplos generalmente les apareceria como `event["date(1i)"]` mientras que yo obtengo algo como `date_of_issue["{}(1i)"]`

Comment: Yo puse `date_of_issue` asumiendo que va la línea anterior en la cual seteas el valor de `params`. Revisa como llegan efectivamente los parámetros al servidor. Para el ejemplo que mencionas, de seguro han usado `form_for @event`, para crear/editar un objeto event, donde el `object_name` va implícito y luego usan algo como `f.date_select :date`, lo cual genera `event["date(1i)"]`. En tu caso estás usando `form_tag`, en cuyo caso no hay un `object_name` implícito (que de hecho está bien, porque no debería aplicar para una búsqueda), así que debes agregarlo tu, aparte del `method`

Comment: Otra opción válida es que agregues un [date_field_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/date_field_tag), que es un input de tipo date de HTML5 y en general [tiene buen soporte](https://caniuse.com/#search=input-date) dentro de los exploradores modernos.